# Porcentaje en hctreemap2 de Highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, porcentaje

Hice un treemap con Highcharter y como el gráfico es interactivo quiero que me muestre tanto la cantidad total y el porcentaje que cada grupo representa del total. Tengo los 2 siguientes códigos, pero de ambas maneras me muestra el porcentaje en 0.00%.

```
#Forma 1
hctreemap2(data =Objeto,
           group_vars = c("objeto_contratar"),
           size_var = "total",
           color_var = "total",
           layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
           levelIsConstant = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[2],
               maxColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[7]) %>%
               hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "Objeto: {point.name} <br>
                            Contratos: {point.value:,.0f} <br>
                            Porcentaje: {point.percentage:.2f} %")  %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)

#Forma 2
hctreemap2(data =Objeto,
           group_vars = c("objeto_contratar"),
           size_var = "total",
           color_var = "total",
           layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
           levelIsConstant = FALSE) %>% 
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[2],
               maxColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[7]) %>%
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function(){
                                return  '</b>'  + this.point.name + ': <br> Contratos: ' +this.point.value+' <br> Porcentage: '+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.percentage)+'%'
  }"),useHTML = FALSE)  %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

Alguien podría decirme cómo hago para que muestre ambos datos (la cantidad y el porcentaje que representa) en el mismo gráfico cuando pongo el puntero sobre él?

Comment: Bienvenido Alejandro a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Hace rato que no se lo ve por acá, pero podríamos intentar invocar a uno de los autores de este paquete: @jbkunst a ver si nos hecha una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La documentación de [Highcharts.tooltip](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.footerFormat) menciona que point.percentage solo esta disponible para gráficos de barras apiladas y gráficos de pastel.

> this.percentage (not shared) / this.points[i].percentage (shared):
> Stacked series and pies only. The point's percentage of the total

Una opción para mostrar el porcentaje en otro tipo de gráficos es usar la opción `formatter` para calcularlo mediante una función en `JS`. En particular para los graficos tipo treemap [Liviu Boboia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3963643/liviu-boboia) dio una función  `formatter` que funciona como [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33570525/8717400) en el sitio en ingles. He incorporado esta solución al ejemplo de [hctreemap2 en RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/highcharter/versions/0.7.0/topics/hctreemap2).

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(RColorBrewer)

#Creeamos datos
df<-data_frame(
  index1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 500, replace = T),
  value = rpois(500, 5),
  color_value = rpois(500, 5)
)


#Creamos un higchart con el treemap
hc<-df %>%
  hctreemap2(
    group_vars = c("index1"),
    size_var = "value",
    color_var = "color_value",
    layoutAlgorithm = "squarified",
    levelIsConstant = FALSE,
    levels = list(
      list(level = 1, dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)),
      list(level = 2, dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE)),
      list(level = 3, dataLabels = list(enabled = FALSE))
    )
  )
```

El siguiente código es el que deberás agregar a tu ejemplo para que calcule el porcentaje y lo muestre en el tooltip. Yo no lo hice con tu ejemplo pues no tenia los datos para replicarlo.

```
hc%>% 
  #Agregamos colores personalizaos
  hc_colorAxis(minColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[2],
               maxColor = brewer.pal(7, "Blues")[7]) %>%
  #Incorporamos una función que calcula el porcentaje de cada
  #categoria y formateamos el tooltip
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS('function () {
                            var total = 0;
                            for (var i = 0; i < this.series.data.length; i++)
                            {
                            if (this.series.data[i].node.children.length == 0)
                            total+=this.series.data[i].node.val;
                            }
                            var value;
                            if (this.point.node.children.length == 0)
                            {
                            value = this.point.options.value;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                            value = this.point.node.childrenTotal;
                            }
                            var porcentage = (value / total) *100;
                            return  "</b>"  + this.point.name + ": <br> Contratos: " +this.point.value+" <br> Porcentage: "+Highcharts.numberFormat(porcentage)+"%"
                            }'),useHTML = FALSE)  %>% 
  hc_exporting(enabled = TRUE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]